# 'val' or 'var', mutable or immutable?

Tags: scala

I can define a variable (by `var`) that is immutable:

```
var x = scala.collection.immutable.Set("aaaaaa","bbbbbb")
println(x.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
x += "cccc"
println(x.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
```

This results in:

```
true
true
```

`+=` method is not a member of `scala.collection.immutable.Set`, so what is happening?

Comment: Note that `x` now holds a *new* collection. I think this behaviour is quite intuitive and intended, if you accept other collection methods that work the same way.

Comment: Trying it with `val x =` will give you clues to the answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The compiler looks for `x.+= ...`, and if it can't find it, then it tries to transform the statement into `x = x + ...` (which only succeeds if `x` is a `var`, or `x` desugars into a call to some `update` method). Since `immutable.Set` implements a `+` operator, and `x` is a `var`, this succeeds.

Comment: Good to know that I've been smart to always avoid the +=/*=/... shortcuts.

Comment: I only today discovered that `map(key) += value` works on mutable maps. Will I enter coder's hell now?

Answer (score 6):

The original immutable set is still unchanged.

Continuing [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074179/val-or-var-mutable-or-immutable/5074202#5074202), the + has created a new set, appended the new item, and returned the new set, leaving the original set object unchanged. So you could say `var y = x; y += "cccc"` and you would have 2 sets instead of 1:

```
var x = scala.collection.immutable.Set("aaaaaa","bbbbbb")
println(x.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
var y = x
y += "cccc"
println(x)
println(y)
println(x.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
println(y.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
```

Getting:

```
> true
> Set(aaaaaa, bbbbbb)
> Set(aaaaaa, bbbbbb, cccc)
> true
> true
```

You see the data structure itself is still immutable, but because you declared a `var`, the assignment is mutable. So it can be repointed to a new object if that is returned. If you change to declaring `x` as a `val`, then you couldn't reassign it to a new address.

If you had used a *mutable* set, then `x` and `y` would point to the same object because the `+` call would have appended the existing set rather than returning a new one (being mutable...):

```
var x = scala.collection.mutable.Set("aaaaaa","bbbbbb")
println(x.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]])
var y = x
y += "cccc"
println(x)
println(y)
```

Get:

```
> Set("aaaaaa","bbbbbb","cccc")
> Set("aaaaaa","bbbbbb","cccc")
```

Voila.