# Append Map[String, String] to a Seq[Map[String, String]]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This drives me crazy, I can't figure out why this gives me an error.

Here an example of my code:

```
var seqOfObjects:Seq[Map[String, String]] = Seq[Map[String, String]]()
for(item <- somelist) {
  seqOfObjects += Map(
     "objectid" -> item(0).toString,
     "category" -> item(1),
     "name" -> item(2),
     "url" -> item(3),
     "owneremail" -> item(4),
     "number" -> item(5).toString)
}
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Map[String, String]
```

But a `Map[String, String]` is exactly what I want to append into my `Seq[Map[String, String]]`.

Why is it saying that my variable `seqOfObjects` expects a `String`??

Anyone have a clue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a += b` means `a = a.+(b)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074202/406435).

There is no method `+` in `Seq`, so you can't use `+=`.

```
scala> Seq[Int]() + 1
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              Seq[Int]() + 1
                           ^
```

`required: String` is from string concatenation. This behavior is inherited from `Java`:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) + "str"
res0: String = List(1, 2, 3)str
```

Actually method `+` here is from [`StringAdd`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.StringAdd) wrapper. See implicit method `Predef.any2stringadd`.

You could use `:+=` or `+:=` instead of `+=`.

Default implementation of `Seq` is `List`, so you should use `+:` and `+:=` instead of `:+` and `:+=`. See [Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) of scala collections.

You could also use `List` instead of `Seq`. There is `::` method in `List`, so you can use `::=`:

```
var listOfInts = List[Int]()
listOfInts ::= 1
```

You can rewrite your code without mutable variables using `map`:

```
val seqOfObjects =
  for(item <- somelist) // somelist.reverse to reverse order
    yield Map(...)
```

To reverse elements order you could use `reverse` method.

Comment: Ok I see, I didn't even think about the += since that wasnt the error. But it looks like it was :)
Thanks @senia, this helps alot!

Answer (score 1):

Short `foldLeft` example:

```
sl.foldLeft(Seq[Map[Srting, String]]()){ (acc, item) =>  Map(/* map from item */) +: acc }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer @Alexlv , I will look into this aswell. Looks intresting!